# INSERT More than 50 Query Using same opened connection

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

So what i basically want is to insert more than 1 query to my database without needing of conn.close than conn.open too many times and also doing try more than 50 times ..

Here is exp for the code :

```
    Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim conn As MySqlConnection
    Dim Item1 As String = "INSERT INTO item_template (entry, name, display) VALUES ('1234', 'Testing', '654';"
    Dim Item3 As String = "UPDATE Item_template SET entry = '123' where name like 'test32111';"
    Dim Item2 As String = "INSERT INTO item_template (entry, name, display) VALUES ('123467', 'Testing332', '65478';"
    Try
        conn.Open()
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Item1, conn)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Try
        conn.Open()
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Item3, conn)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Try
        conn.Open()
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Item2, conn)
        reader = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Comment: You can use procedure instead

Comment: insert multiple rows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/452934/832052

Comment: Have you tried stacking the sql commands in the same string and execute the contatenated string? Alternativaly, save everything into a .sql file and run the file.

Comment: @carlos Sorry didn't understand what you mean ?

Comment: @pedro I know about that yeah, i already have something like that but this is different the SQL also have update and other insert and replace and update etc.... so i want to run them all together instead of doing the method i posted..

Comment: @djv i already know that method i will fix my post to fit the requirements..

Comment: Recheck my post now to see how it is gonna be..

Comment: Just open the connection once, run all the commands you wish to run, then close the connection at the end?

Comment: You don't need to close and reopen the connection between queries; open the connection at the start, do your queries, then close. _You can even reuse the command object by using its CommandText property to set the current query; but make sure the clear the parameters if/when you start using parameterized queries._

Comment: Also, your values lists are missing their closing `)`.

Comment: If you have triggers on those tables, you would want to do a single command with multiple insert. If not then it may not matter.

Comment: @JNevill well that doesn't work, it will just insert first query and ignore others ...

Comment: @Uueerdo Yeah like i said it will just insert only first one and ignore others also my queries are pretty long that's why i made just simple queries so i can explain my issue :)

Comment: @JohnEvenetcha I'm pretty certain it will not. Unless you have a setting ticked where you need to commit each transaction after submitting ([more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit?view=netframework-4.7.2))

Comment: @JNevill I'm not saying :D xD it says already :p i means i tried it please can you show me exp on how it could be as answer ? and i'll see maybe i was doing something wrong..

Comment: Ah, I think I see your (original) problem; you need to close readers... or just use command's ExecuteNonQuery method.

Comment: Exactly :D haha so can you please post on how i could make it clearly ? and thank you

Comment: Oh @uueerdo that's a good catch. Instead of sending setting up your `reader` you just do [COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery();](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) Or close your reader between commands (but why open them at all?  There is nothing to "read" from an INSERT or UPDATE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some optimizations you can make. You should embed the disposable resources in a [Using-Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(vb.Using)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%3Dv4.5.2)%3Bk(DevLang-VB)%26rd%3Dtrue). The Using statement automatically closes and disposes the resources at the end. Especially the connection will be closed automatically. It does so, even if the Using-block is left prematurely because of an exception or because a Return statement terminates the method.

Keep the connection open while processing the batch.

DRY: [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Try to avoid code repetition make with copy paste. In the following example I create an array of SQL texts that can be processed in a loop.

SQL commands like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE do not return a result set. Use [`ExecuteNonQuery`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm) instead of [`ExecuteReader`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteReader.htm) for them.

The command can be resued by assigning it a new command text.

```
Dim sqlTexts = {
    "INSERT INTO item_template (entry, name, display) VALUES ('1234', 'Testing', '654';",
    "UPDATE Item_template SET entry = '123' where name like 'test32111';",
    "INSERT INTO item_template (entry, name, display) VALUES ('12367', 'Testing332', '65478';"
}

Using _
    conn As New MySqlConnection(connectionString),
    command As New MySqlCommand With {
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
        .Connection = conn
    }

    conn.Open()
    For Each sql As String In sqlTexts
        Try
            command.CommandText = sql
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    Next
End Using
```

Note that the Using-statement includes the `command` as well as we are using VB's [Implicit Line Continuation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/statements#implicit-line-continuation) feature as for the initialization of the `sqlTexts` array.

Comment: Thanks very much ! i just can't accept both answers or it's possible as your is great and the other is nice too ! thanks ;)

Comment: It's up to you to decide which answer helps you the most.

Comment: i will pick urs just because there is more than 600 SQL line :D different hehe doing  other method is more easy to understand but yours is really great :)

Comment: Is it possible to add progress bar to this so people know that it will take long :D

Comment: See: [Make Progress Bar Running From Public Class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17031667/880990)

Comment: It's fine i got better method which works great :) thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Without addressing other matters like parameterized/prepared queries, the simplest fix should be...

```
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Dim conn As MySqlConnection
Dim Item1 As String = "INSERT INTO item_template (entry, name, display) VALUES ('1234', 'Testing', '654');"
Dim Item3 As String = "UPDATE Item_template SET entry = '123' where name like 'test32111';"
Dim Item2 As String = "INSERT INTO item_template (entry, name, display) VALUES ('123467', 'Testing332', '65478');"
Try
    conn.Open()
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("", conn)
    COMMAND.CommandText = Item1
    COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery
    COMMAND.CommandText = Item2
    COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery
    COMMAND.CommandText = Item3
    COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery
    conn.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

My VB is a little rusty though, so beware of typo-level errors *(I tried to add `;` more than once)*

Comment: Thanks actually just remove the dim reader as mysqldatareader :D as it's not needed :)